# How to calculate simple moving average from list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, average

I use a robin_stocks module here to calculate stock historicals and then sort them by date.

```
import robin_stocks as r

stock_price = r.stocks.get_stock_historicals('F', interval='day', span='week', bounds='regular')
stock_price = sorted(stock_price, key=lambda item: item['begins_at'])
for stock in stock_price:
    print('Stock: {}, Date: {}, Open: {}, Close: {}'.format(stock['symbol'],stock['begins_at'],stock['open_price'],stock['close_price']))
```

Output:

```
Stock: F, Date: 2020-06-24T00:00:00Z, Open: 6.060000, Close: 5.950000
Stock: F, Date: 2020-06-25T00:00:00Z, Open: 5.860000, Close: 6.030000
Stock: F, Date: 2020-06-26T00:00:00Z, Open: 6.040000, Close: 5.910000
Stock: F, Date: 2020-06-29T00:00:00Z, Open: 5.910000, Close: 6.010000
Stock: F, Date: 2020-06-30T00:00:00Z, Open: 5.980000, Close: 6.080000
```

I want to know how to calculate the average of the 'close'.

Comment: Have a look at putting your data into a `pandas.DataFrame`.  This has a `rolling` function on which you can calculate the rolling mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
close_prices = [float(stock['close_price']) for stock in stock_price]
avg = sum(close_prices) / len(close_prices)
```

If you wish to apply rolling mean with custom window sizes and use `pandas`, you can do it with `pandas.DataFrame.rolling`.

Comment: Um I get this error:  avg = sum(close_prices) / len(close_prices)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Are the values under `close_price` string? Try `[float(stock['close_price']) for stock in stock_price]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a dictionary as the title says (instead of the "print" shown in your code) you can convert it to a dataframe with:

```
import pandas as pd

your_df = pd.DataFrame(your_dict)
```

and once you have the dataframe you can create a new column with the moving average with:

```
your_df['SMA'] = your_df['Close'].rolling(window=10,center=False).mean()
```

Also, you can change the window of days from 10 to whatever number you prefer.

Comment: This is is awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compute the sum in your `for` loop:

```
close_sum = 0
for stock in stock_price:
    print('Stock: {}, Date: {}, Open: {}, Close: {}'.format(stock['symbol'],stock['begins_at'],stock['open_price'],stock['close_price']))
    close_sum += float(stock['close_price'])
```

Then divide the sum by the stock count:

```
close_average = close_sum / len(stock_price)
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error:  close_sum += stock['close_price']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'                                         
  any ideas?

Comment: @CameronRosenbaum You must compute with numbers, not strings. The error comes from your input, so it affects all the answers. Just apply the `float()` conversion, just like [suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676194/how-to-calculate-simple-moving-average-from-list-of-dicts/62676349?noredirect=1#comment110838593_62676289). My answer has been updated.